# url templatetag in django and direct_to_template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use the `url` templatetag in django, but the url I want to resolve is associated to something that is rendered through direct_to_template, so I don't have a view function to pass to `url`. Is it possible to use it in any case, or should I create a trivial view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name the URL in your urlconf, you can use that with the `url` templatetag. In your urlconf:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(
        r'^whatever/your/url/pattern/is/$',
        direct_to_template,
        { 'template': 'wherever/your/template/is.html' },
        name='name-of-url'
    ),
)
```

In your template:

```
{% url name-of-url %}
```

This is covered in [Naming URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2) in the Django documentation.